# Mercurial repository on FTP

Tags: mercurial, ftp

I wonder, if it's possible to create and serve to the clients Mercurial repository on the 
some FTP folder with RW access . Did someone do a thing like that ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All things are possible.  But that would be hard.

The bit where the network transport matters is when cloning a repository, and the [standard ways of doing that](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html) depend on either serving over HTTP, or having SSH access to the repository host.  There's no FTP-based transport for cloning as far as I can see.

If that's the *only* sharing mechanism you have available, then you could probably work something out using [Mercurial bundles](http://www.soton.ac.uk/~fangohr/computing/hg.html#use-mercurial-without-access-to-server-using-bundles).  The procedure would be something like the following:

1. Commit your edits to a local repository
2. Make a bundle using `hg bundle --all my-bundle.hg`
3. FTP `my-bundle.hg` to the server

The other users of the repository can then use FTP to retrieve the `my-bundle.hg` file to their local machine, go to their local copy of the repository, and then `hg pull my-bundle.hg` to pull in any revisions which are in the bundle but not in the local repository.  When they want to share their changes, they make a fresh bundle as above, and push that back to the server.  The `--all` option puts *all* of the changesets into the bundle file -- you can be cleverer and only export 'recent' changes, but that gets a little more complicated and risks losing changesets: using `--all` is brutal but fail-safe.

There's obviously a fair amount of scope for confusion here, and race conditions (timestamped filenames might help), and hair-pulling-out, and your users would doubtless appreciate some scripts to make this easier, but if all you've got available is an FTP server, you don't have very many options.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness, because I had the same problem and feel that there is another, much simpler solution:

Mercurial cloning on local folders "just works", so if you mounted the ftp as a local folder or drive, you could just push/pull/clone to that (and have your repository end up on the ftp).

On Windows, you can e.g. use [FTPUse](http://www.ferrobackup.com/ftpuse/) or [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net) to have your FTP folder mounted as a local drive, the former is free but a CLI tool which removes the virtual drives if the program is closed, the latter has a GUI but is only free for personal use and doesn't work (yet) on Win8. I don't have a Linux machine at hand now, but you should be able to achieve the same using ftpfs.

Once you did it (and your ftp server is now mapped e.g. to f:), you can simply use that virtual drive (or any subfolder) as a remote target for your mercurial operations. Works like a charm for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither works for me on Windows 7 64-bit. I can mount FTP as drive just fine, but Mercurial gives various errors about "file not found" or similar, when trying to do clone or push. Locally, it works, so it seems to not be reliable on all systems.

Answer (score 0):

[This question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/123052/keeping-local-windows-folder-in-sync-with-remote-ftp-folder-in-real-time) might be interesting. The core idea seem to evolve around running a background process that synchronizes a local folder with a remote ftp folder. Which might of use to you.

But I dont know what happens when more than one user tries synchronize at the same time. Since using this approach bypasses all the protection that mercurial has regarding locking the tree and such.